# Center floating divs in the body

Tags: html, css

I have something like 3 divs, which are floating to left. They are like 1200 width, but I have resolution 1400. When my browser will be < 1200 last div is going to bottom. It's ok, but now I would like to center them when my resolution is better than 1200 width.

I am not best on CSS so I've tried to use display: table-cell but it won't help.

## HTML

```
<section class="main-items">
    <div class="items-left">
        <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout1" runat="server">
</div>
    <div class="items-left">
        <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout2" runat="server">
</div>
    <div class="items-left">
        <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout3" runat="server">
</div>
</section>
```

## CSS

```
.main-items {

}
.items-left {
    float: left;
   
}
```

Comment: Could You please explain once more the effect You want to have? I can help, but I can't understand when divs should be centered, and when float left...

Comment: OK. I have 3 DIVs. They are from left to right. If they cant display, last one go bottom. 

3 DIVs are about 1200 width. If I have browser with resolution bigger than 1200 width items are not display in center but from left to right. I want to display they in the middle. Like you have text header in the middle because of text-align: center;

Comment: The way to center block elements is to give them a specific width, and apply `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` - see answer below.

Comment: Ok, thx for clarification :). But it was too late I think :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a wrapper div to center the three of them.

```
<section class="main-items">
    <div class="items-left">
       <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout1" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div class="items-left">
        <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout2" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div class="items-left">
        <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout3" runat="server">
    </div>
 </section>
```

In your CSS file, insert the CSS attributes

```
.main-items {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Or you could center each **item-left** element individually, through CSS, as Zougen Moriver pointed out. ;)

Comment: Good point, why was I centering them all individually when he already has a wrapper element around them all?

Comment: He doesn't, Zougen. Adding a wrapper element was my suggestion, as a different approach from the one you suggested, that may work in IE8 or less.

Comment: It is working fine. I just adjust width, and now is everything correct.

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice it at first. I have edited my answer to use `<section class="main-items">` as the wrapper. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a media query to acheive this, as long as you don't need to support IE8 or less.

```
.items-left {
    float: left;
}

/* When the browser window is 1200px or wider... */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .main-items {
         width: 1200px;
         margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .items-left {
         float: none;
    }
}
```